# TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailchimp

So I am trying to create a signup page using mailchimp API. but as soon as start my server and put my name. it gives me this error and i don't understand why this is happening cause i havent used any listener. Thanks for the help.

```
      app.post("/", function(req,res){
            const firstName = req.body.fName;
            const secondName = req.body.sName;
            const emailAddress = req.body.eAddress;
            const data = {
                members:[
                    {
                        email_address: emailAddress,
                        status: "subscribed",
                        merge_fields: {
                            FNAME: firstName,
                            LNAME: secondName
                        }
                    }
                ]
            };
            const JSONdata = JSON.stringify(data);
            const url = "https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/e5efed23f3";
            const options = {
                method : "POST",
                auth: "aadi2305://APIKEY is here"
            }
//It shows error on the following line
            const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){
                response.on("data", function(data){
                    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                })
            })
        
            request.write(JSONdata);
            request.end();
        })
```

Comment: which line of that code is throwing the error?

Comment: i commented that line. const request = https.request .....

Comment: Is your node.js version greater than 10.9?

Comment: Yeah. I just updated it

Comment: Did that fix the problem? What version were you running? What are you running now?

Comment: yeah man. thanks. i was running on version 8